# Creating DataFrame and using loops

Tags: r

I've never really used RStudio before for coding, only statistical data analysis. I'm importing data as a csv and I'm trying to loop through it to create a new dataframe but I have no idea how to go about that.

```
data <- read.csv("Maks.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

the csv has over 98 images that I want to create add in a new table like format.

```
cutOrUn <- substring(data$V1, 5, 6)
```

this substring determines whether the image will have a "yes" or "no" in its first column depending on the character there. And its what I compare to in the for loops if statement.

```
for(image in data$V1){
  if(identical(cutOrUn, "C-") || identical(cutOrUn, "_C")) {
    imageCol <- c(imageCol,paste("yes", sep = " "))
  } else if(identical(cutOrUn, "S-") || identical(cutOrUn, "_S")){
    imageCol (not sure what to do here?)
  }
}

//data$V1 is the first column of the csv with the image names.So I'm
```

//looping through all images.

i'm not sure how to add to imageCol (just a variable i'm using to store yes or no) for both the if and else if statements. I would rather just directly add to the new dataframe if i could rather than store in another variable and then have to go through and add. but i'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The `r-studio` tag is for questions which are specifically about the R Studio IDE, not questions about R itself.

Comment: 1) You loop `for(image in data$V1)` but don't use `image`  in the loop. 2) You `grep` this and that and don't use the results. 3) I bet you don't need loops at all.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the problem makes me think that the following vectorized code can do what you want.

```
cut1 <- cutOrUn %in% c("C-", "_C")
uncut1 <- cutOrUn %in% c("S-", "_S")

imageCol <- character(length(cutOrUn))
imageCol[cut1] <- "yes"
imageCol[uncut1] <- "no"
```

(Untested, since there is no example dataset.)